# HTML: img tag near a input

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem, when i'm adding a img tag near a input and a span the img causing the input and the sapn to lower down.

```
<div>
   <span>נקודות זיכוי</span>
   <input type="text" name="nekodot_zikoy" value="2.25"/>
   <img src="images/cal_black.png" title="חשב נקודות זיכוי" alt="חשב נקודות זיכוי"/>
</div>
```

I have the code here http://jsfiddle.net/49JcA/

just don't mind that there is no images if you take the tag out and see what i talking about..

Thank's!

Comment: You should use label instead of span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the span and input to appear on top, just add `align="top"` to the image:

```
<img src="images/cal_black.png" align="top" ... />
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49JcA/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align`, for instance:

```
* { vertical-align:top; }
```

But note, you **do not** want to do it like this. Others may argue that you shouldn't even use `vertical-align` like this, but I won't complain about that if it works for you, but specifying this globally (using `*`) is wrong and bad for performance. Instead you should apply it to the elements you need, which vary in this case. So, something like this:

```
input[type=text] { vertical-align:top; }
```

And any other elements you need this applied to.

Lastly, you should be labeling input for compliance.

Comment: it's ok to insert lable without any attributes? or should i need to put the name of the input in for="input name"